# Duration for two button clicks returns false values

Tags: java, android, date, buttonclick, milliseconds

I'm trying to calculate break time user takes by click on before user takes break and click on another button when he finish break. I stumbled upon few questions and read that best method is to use nanoTime() method.

```
System.nanoTime();
```

But the problem is when I calculate the duration it returns weird value.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my code,

```
        btnStartBreak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                breakStartTime = System.nanoTime();
                breakTv.setText("Do you want to finish the break?");
                btnStartBreak.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnFinishBreak.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        btnFinishBreak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                breakFinishTime = System.nanoTime();
                long breakTime = breakFinishTime - breakStartTime;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getDate(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(breakTime), "mm:ss:SSS"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat){
        // Create a DateFormatter object for displaying date in specified format.
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

        // Create a calendar object that will convert the date and time value in milliseconds to date.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
        }
```

I have used this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert milliseconds to hours and minutes.

Comment: So you're calling `getDate` which takes the time in **milliseconds**, yet you provide the time in **nanoseconds**?
You're off by a factor of 1,000,000.

Comment: Oh, that is the case.

Comment: Well I used TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(breakTime) but now it shows 31:45:284 value just for two minutes duration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*I'll provide my comment as answer here with additional info.*

You're using `System.nanotime()` which, according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29),

> Returns the current value of the most precise available system timer, in nanoseconds.

But your method `getDate()` requires the time in milliseconds. So the value you provide is 1,000,000 times too big.

Instead, you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` which will give you the needed time in milliseconds.

**Edit:**

It seems that you want to calculate a timespan and display it in the form `minutes:seconds:millis`. Don't use `Calendar` and/or `Date` for that. And you don't need `SimpleDateFormat`.

You already have the time difference between the two actions. There's a much simpler approach to format that timespan. You can use the following snippet for converting:

```
public static String formatMillis(long ms) {
    long rest = ms;
    long minutes = rest / (1000 * 60);

    rest = rest % (1000 * 60);
    long seconds = rest / 1000;
    long millis = rest % 1000;

    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%03d", minutes, seconds, millis);
}
```

Input:

```
formatMillis(5000L);
formatMillis(60000L);
formatMillis(67890L);
```

Output:

```
00:05:000
01:00:000
01:07:890
```

Comment: Before I use nanoTime() I used currentTimeMillis() method. But it didn't work properly. That's why I chose to use this method.

Comment: Yeah, I tried formatMillis() method and it's output is correct. Thank you so much!

Comment: currentTimeMillis() depends on system clock, hence it is not recommeded.

Answer (score 2):

I have done a little experiment on your code, have used both `System.nanoTime()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` and on both case i have succeed.

**Using System.currentTimeMillis()**

```
long breakStartTime, breakTime;
 btnStartBreak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                breakStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                breakTv.setText("Do you want to finish the break?");
                btnStartBreak.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnFinishBreak.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    btnFinishBreak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            breakTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - breakStartTime ;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getDate(breakTime, "mm:ss.SSS"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

**Using  System.nanoTime()**
`nanoTime()`is specifically designed to measure elapsed time, while `currentTimeMillis()` relies on what time the system's clock is set to, which can be changed. So its always better to use `nanoTime()` for calculating elapsed time.

```
long breakStartTime, breakTime , durationInMs;
btnStartBreak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    breakStartTime = System.nanoTime();
                    breakTv.setText("Do you want to finish the break?");
                    btnStartBreak.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnFinishBreak.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

    btnFinishBreak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            breakTime = System.nanoTime() - breakStartTime ;
            //convert nanoseconds value to milliseconds
            durationInMs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(breakTime , TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getDate(durationInMs, "mm:ss.SSS"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, +1 for comparing between nanoTime() and currentTimeMillis() and recommendation for nanoTime().